# How do I insert strings into an NSArray and return them later for printing or comparing?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nslog

I am trying to create a NSMutableArray of size 100 and then fill every index with the a string of three blank spaces, `"   "`. I am either creating the array incorrectly **or** I am returning the objects incorrectly. Here is my method that creates the array:

```
-(void) initBoard{
    _board = [board initWithCapacity:100];
    for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){
        [_board addObject:@"   "];
    }
}
```

This method is not functioning properly. I added an a for loop after the one above that contained `NSLog @"@%", [_board objectAtIndex: i];` so that I could verify that there were actually strings comprised of three blank spaces at every index, but all that it would print out in the console was "nil". So far I have tried:

- I thought that maybe the `addObjectAtIndex` was the problem so I just changed it to `addObject` and changed the `initWithCapacity` to just `init];` to allow the for loop to build the array to size 100.
- Then I thought that maybe the problem was with trying to insert the literal string, `@"   "` (IDK how to make Stackoverflow show my 3 spaces, not just 1), so I added `NSString *input = @"   ";` right before the for loop, and then changed `[_board addObject:@"   "];` to `[_board addObject:input;

Any suggestions on how to actually create an NSMutableArray of size 100 and make every spot contain the same string of three blank spaces?

Comment: You almost certainly failed to allocate the array.

Comment: I thought I had the `alloc` statement in my .h file. It wasn't. I get confused by the .h file, and don't understand when you would NOT use a alloc, why does it not just do that by defualt?

Comment: I've never seen an `alloc` in an .h file.  `alloc` is a procedure, and you never call procedures in a standard .h file.  Plus, in Objective-C, you should *always* have the `alloc` and `init...` together, unless you *really* understand what you're doing and the full implications of doing it.

Comment: If you're not understanding this you probably need to go back and learn C first.  Then find a good book on Objective-C -- don't try to figure it out from the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `alloc`ate and than `init`ialize the mutable array:

```
-(void) initBoard{
    _board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){
        [_board addObject:@"   "];
    }
}
```